# AutoFocus on Framework 7 Searchbar not working

Tags: search, mobile, vue.js, html-framework-7, searchbar

So i have a mobile app with 5 tabs one of which is the search tab and i would like that every time i click on the search tab the search comes automatically enabled and the keyboard pops up also meaning that the cursor will be ready in place.I search in the html in the browser and found out that everytime i click on the search bar to write something a new class is added called input-focused so i tried to add this automatically using a methos called enable and which is calling the method searchEnabled but still its not working... any ideas?

```
<f7-searchbar
   @searchbar:enable="searchEnabled"
   @searchbar:search="search"
   search-container=".search-list"
   search-in=".item-title"
></f7-searchbar>


methods: {
  search (searchbar, query) {
    if (query === '') {
      this.results = []
    } else {
      this.filter.q = query
      Search.filter(this.filter).then(({data}) => {
        this.results = data
      })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('error:', error)
        })
    }
  },
  searchEnabled (searchbar) {
    searchbar.$inputEl[0].classList.add(['input-focused'])
  }
}
```